# ASP.NET Core Web Application using Azure AD, Log logins locally

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, authentication, logging, web-applications

I am using .NET Core 3.1 and I am using AzureAd for Authentication.    I have a SQL backend and I would like to log in a table when a user logs in.  The table already has a list of users with their domain user name so I can link based on the name claim.

My issue is where can I intercept the point where AzureAd returns to the application?  Or is there a different point in the login process where I can do this?

VS 2019 created the code when I created the project   It created the following in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Comment: Can you show how you're setting it up in ConfigureServices? [AddAzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.azureadauthenticationbuilderextensions.addazuread) is supposed to be obsolete.

Comment: services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));